# Replacing elements of a column in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have 2 vectors:

```
a = c("1", "2", "3")

b = c("a", "b", "c")
```

and a data frame with a column that is equal to `c("1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "2")`.

What I want to do is to replace everything in the column that is equal to the items in vector a with the items in vector b (everything in the column that is equal to a[1] will turn into b[1]).

As in I want my new column to be `c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "b")`.

I know I have to use some sort of loop but everything that I have tried does not work.

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: `x <- c("1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "2"); b[match(x, a)]`

Comment: Regarding the statement that you "have to use some sort of loop": it may be a useful exercise to browse chapters 3 and 4 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Thinking iteratively when solving problems in R will often lead you astray. Vectorising code takes practice, but it's a valuable skill that will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to do that.

```
c <- c("1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "2")
match(c, a)
#[1] 1 1 2 1 3 2
b[match(c, a)]
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "a" "c" "b"
```